# Compiz - Can I Disable Switching the Workspace While Dragging a Window

Tags: ubuntu, window, compiz

This bums me, cause I am a huge fan of window snapping. Whenever I drag a window to the left or right of my screen, the cube shows, and the window moves to the previous/next workspace. This interferes with window snapping, can I disable this or configure it in such a way that I will need to press a key combo while moving for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Open the CompizConfig Settings Manager by running `ccsm` in your terminal or starting it from the launcher. Install it if it's missing (obviously).

In ccsm, click on "Rotate cube" and uncheck "Edge flip move".
This should lead to the desired result.